# Removing duplicates from foreach

Tags: php, template-lite

I have  a query like this

```
SELECT TOWN, NAME FROM CINEMA WHERE CITY_ID = ".$_POST['country']." GROUP BY TOWN, NAME
```

In view side, I take the values with the help of template_lite

```
   <table border="1" >
        <br />
 {foreach value=mp from=$mpbycity}
 <tr><td>{$mp.TOWN}</td></tr>
  <tr><td>{$mp.NAME}</td></tr>

 {/foreach}
    </table>
```

The problem is the duplicates.You can see from below pic.

I tried array_unique but it does not work.

[image]

Comment: Your SQL looks wonky. It would be helpful to see your table structure in your database.

Comment: `TOWN` is the same, `VALUE` isn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you must filter variable before writing inside query `..CITY_ID = ".$_POST['country']."`. With this code attacker can inject code on query. Check [Sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). To avoid this use [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

```
..CITY_ID = ".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['country'])."...
```

And to unique array, you can use `array_unique()`,  `SELECT DISTINCT`, `GROUP BY` clauses. Also in loop can avoid to write duplicate values to array. All depends on your database structure and query.

Answer (score 0):

You are not seing duplicates. Basically, you are iterating over group by syntax and you are printing them in two diff lines.

The output you have is like

```
A B 
A C 
A D

B C 
B D 
B E
```

and you printing it as

```
A
B
A
C
A
D
B
C
B
E
```

,
which you think is duplicate.

The combination {$mp.TOWN} and {$mp.NAME} combined is unique.